# Uncompleted code Shiny App, mtcars dataset, how to make four user inputs to four different graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm unsure of the code I need to put in the mainPanel portion to have the mainPanel graph change based on the user input.

I have four working graphs all tied to the mtcars dataset:

first graph, lets call "counts":

```
counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
          barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", 
          xlab="Number of Gears")
```

second graph lets call "Horizontal Counts":

```
Horizontalcounts <- table(mtcars$gear)
                   barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", horiz=TRUE,
                   names.arg=c("3 Gears", "4 Gears", "5 Gears"))
```

third graph lets call "stacked bar chart":

```
stackedbarchart <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
                   barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
                   xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
                   legend = rownames(counts))
```

and the fourth graph called "grouped bar chart":

```
groupedbarchart <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
                  barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
                  xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
                  legend = rownames(counts), beside=TRUE)
```

I want to do the following with Shiny, the user has four options ( the four charts listed above) when one is selected, the graph will then show. So a simple shiny app, user selects a graph and the graph shows up on the main panel.

I have the following code and it runs, but the graphs do not show up:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


setwd("wd")
myData <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(
     titlePanel("cars graphs"),
     sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(selectInput("carsInput", " car graph Choice",
                         choices = c("counts", "Horizontal counts", "stacked bar chart", "grouped bar chart"), 
                          selected = "counts" )),
        mainPanel( plotOutput("unsure?"),
                    br(), br(),
                     tableOutput("results")
    )
 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

       output$plotOutput <- reactive({
            if (input$carsInput == "counts")
        {


  counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
  barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", 
          xlab="Number of Gears")

    }
if (input$carsInput == "horizontal counts")
  {

  counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
  barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", horiz=TRUE,
          names.arg=c("3 Gears", "4 Gears", "5 Gears"))

}

if (input$carsInput == "stacked bar chart")
{


  counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
  barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
          xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
          legend = rownames(counts))

}
if (input$carsInput == "grouped bar chart")
{


  counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
  barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
          xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
          legend = rownames(counts), beside=TRUE)

}
}

 } )


 }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm unsure of the code I need to put in the mainPanel portion to have the mainPanel graph change based on the user input. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use renderPlot if you want to see plots in UI like this

```
 library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)



    myData <- mtcars

    ui <- fluidPage(
        titlePanel("cars graphs"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(selectInput("carsInput", " car graph Choice",
                                     choices = c("counts", "Horizontal counts", "stacked bar chart", "grouped bar chart"), 
                                     selected = "counts" )),
            mainPanel( plotOutput("plotOutput"),
                       br(), br(),
                       tableOutput("results")
            )
        )
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {

        output$plotOutput <- renderPlot({
            if (input$carsInput == "counts")
            {


                counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
                barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", 
                        xlab="Number of Gears")

            }
            if (input$carsInput == "Horizontal counts")
            {

                counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
                barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", horiz=TRUE,
                        names.arg=c("3 Gears", "4 Gears", "5 Gears"))

            }

            if (input$carsInput == "stacked bar chart")
            {


                counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
                barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
                        xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
                        legend = rownames(counts))

            }
            if (input$carsInput == "grouped bar chart")
            {


                counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
                barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
                        xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
                        legend = rownames(counts), beside=TRUE)

            }
        })

    } 



    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```